# Create curve customView layout

Tags: android, view, custom-view

I have created simple custom view that i extend from `RelativeLayout`

I have created this shape:

```
        firstPoint.set(0,100);
        secondPoint.set(getWidth(),100);
        thirdPoint.set(getWidth(),getHeight());
        fourthPoint.set(0,getHeight());

        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((getWidth() / 5) * 4 , 100);
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set((getWidth() /6) * 5, 0);

        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + 100  , mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x -100 , mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);
```

[image]

I want to be curve red line that i mentioned on image but my code `curve section` is mistake and i can not choose right number to create right curve..I think this values is wrong:

```
 mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + 100  , mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
 mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x -100 , mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);
```

This is ondraw method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mPath.lineTo(firstPoint.x,firstPoint.y);
    mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x,mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
    mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x,mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

    mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
            mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
            mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

    mPath.lineTo(thirdPoint.x,thirdPoint.y);
    mPath.lineTo(fourthPoint.x,fourthPoint.y);
    mPath.close();
    canvas.drawPath(mPath,mPaint);
}
```

Comment: what shape do you want to draw? a rounded tab bar? why not to use `NinePatchDrawable`?

Comment: I do not know about `NinePatchDrawable`.I want to create curve path like read line for step one and for step to create other curve path line inverse of step one .I want to make dome shape top of my layer.This is other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246536/create-curve-layout-to-use-bottom-sheet-android  I want to make this layear @pskink

Comment: path.moveTo(10, 80);
path.rCubicTo(30, 0, 30, -70, 70, -70);
path.rCubicTo(40, 0, 40, 70, 70, 70);

Comment: dude this is an example or it is working in my code ? @pskink

Comment: dude do you have any tutorial to read, i have no idea who your code is working . .Thank you so much@pskink

Comment: read `Path` class documentation

Comment: I saw this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path but it is just writing methods and there is not any explanation and example @pskink

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve or  https://javascript.info/bezier-curve or https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/

Comment: Thanks dude . you and this tool so help me to understanding this subject http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/canvas-curves/bezier-curve.html